# Difference in #define in C - char vs char*

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Wanted to ask what is the difference between:

```
#define STR 'a'
```

and

```
#define STR "a"
```

I think the difference is that the first one is passed as a single `char` and the second one is passed as a `char*` and is a two-character array like: `['a','\0']`.

Comment: Neither macro definition is correct actually, as you don't give any name to the macro. And nothing is *passed*, the preprocessor is a relatively simple search-replace kind of thing, dealing only with text.

Comment: There is no difference as they are both invalid.

Comment: I forgot to add the name, fixed it now

Comment: `#define` knows nothing about C types. It's a text substitution tool. If you want to know about the difference between `'a'` and `"a"` then yes, one is a character and the other is a 2-character array, but `#define` doesn't care.

Comment: Neither of them is a `char*`. `'a'` is a `char` and `"a"` is a `char[2]`. Although if `"a"` is used in most expressions, it will be replaced with a `char*` pointing to its first element.

Comment: By the way, in C almost all instances of characters will be implicitly converted to `int`. Even when using actual literal characters like `'a'`.

Comment: The difference between `'a'` and `"a"` is addressed by any beginner learning material. That they sit behind a `#define` in this case is irrelevant.

Comment: In C, `'a'` is an `int`, not a `char` (maybe things are different in C++).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just got the whole point of macros wrong. Macros are typeless. They are of no datatype. They are just text. Just text.

Eg.

```
#define X 'a'
printf("%c\n", X);
```

This will first be preprocessed and result in this code:

```
printf("%c\n", 'a');
```

Then this code will be compiled and you will get your assembly.

If you have this code:

```
#define X WobbleWobbleJobbleTheDobble__
printf("%d\n", X);
```

Then the preprocessor will produce this:

```
printf("%d\n", WobbleWobbleJobbleTheDobble__);
```

Obviously the compilation will fail but the preprocessor doesn't care. All that macors do is replace text.

```
#define X "a"
```

The preprocessor will look for the identifier `X` in the entire code and replace it with `"a"`. Macros are just text.

Btw, yes what you think in the last paragraph is right for things like:

```
void *ch = "a";
```

`ch` actually has a type and is not text like macros.

Comment: Re “They are just text. Simple text.”: Macro replacement works on preprocessor tokens, not simple text.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yeah actually. But by "simple", I mean that text in general is simple.  I don't mean text that is simple but "simple" describes a quality about all the text in the entire world. I just mean in comparison to datatypes, text is simple. I'll clean that up anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Macros aren't objects. They don't have any meaning until being replaced

In C `'a'` is a [character constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/character_constant) of type `int`, and `"a"` is a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal) of type `char[N]` (with N = 2 in this case). But there's much more than that. Firstly, multiple consecutive string literals will be concatenated into a single literal. For example the below snippet [will print `xyzabca`](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:33,endLineNumber:6,positionColumn:5,positionLineNumber:5,selectionStartColumn:33,selectionStartLineNumber:6,startColumn:5,startLineNumber:5),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++%23define+STR+%22a%22%0A++++const+char+str1%5B%5D+%3D+%22xyz%22+STR+%22bc%22%3B%0A++++printf(%22%25s%22+STR+%22%5Cn%22,+str1)%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:37.94142980189491,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1200,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+12.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:62.05857019810508,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+x86-64+clang+12.0.0%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:62.05857019810508,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4):

```
#define STR "a"
const char str1[] = "xyz" STR "bc";
printf("%s" STR "\n", str1);
```

As you can see, the content of the `STR` macro is just a part of the final result. There's no `"a"` array in the output and the resulting literal isn't a 2-character array. You can't concatenate character constants like that

Another thing is that both character and string literals can have prefixes like `L`, `U`, `u`, `u8`... so the resulting text after replacement may be a completely different type

```
#define CONCAT2(str) L##str
#define CONCAT(str)  CONCAT2(str)
#define STR_S        "a"
#define STR_C        'a'

int main() {
    wchar_t c = STR_C;
    printf("wstring: %ls, wchar_t: %lc\n", CONCAT(STR_S), CONCAT(STR_C));
}
```

So there's no `char[N]` in the above code at all, only `wchar_t[N]`. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:11,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:11,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:11,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:11),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%0A%23define+CONCAT2(str)+L%23%23str%0A%23define+CONCAT(str)++CONCAT2(str)%0A%23define+STR_S++++++++%22a%22%0A%23define+STR_C++++++++!%27a!%27%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++wchar_t+c+%3D+STR_C%3B%0A++++printf(%22wstring:+%25ls,+wchar_t:+%25lc%5Cn%22,+CONCAT(STR_S),+CONCAT(STR_C))%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:37.94142980189491,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1200,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+12.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:62.05857019810508,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+x86-64+clang+12.0.0%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:62.05857019810508,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)